# Idiomatic method to convert Array into ListBuffer

Tags: scala, type-conversion, idioms

I'm looking for a cleaner solution than this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

val y = Array(1,2,3,4)
val z = new ListBuffer[Int]()
y.foreach(elem => z += elem)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
val z = ListBuffer(y: _ *)
```

`ListBuffer.apply` accepts a varargs style sequence of elements. The signature is `apply[A](elems: A *): ListBuffer[A]` In order to apply a sequence to a function like this, we use the syntax `: _ *`

Comment: Cool, it works. Could you add a sentence or two explaining how it works, I don't understand this constructor type or the `*` operator you're using

Answer (score 10):

Another way is to use `to` conversion method:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

val arr: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
val buf: ListBuffer[Int] = arr.to[ListBuffer]
```

Type annotations on variables are, of course, superfluous, I've added them only for clarity.

`to` is very versatile, it allows conversion between arbitrary collections (that is, from anything `Traversable` to anything which has an appropriate `CanBuildFrom` instance in scope).